# publishing a conference paper in a journal

Tags: publications, journals, conference

some years ago (2007) I have published a  paper in a conference as a poster paper. Now I want to send it to a journal and change the affiliation, or maybe some minor changes. I didn't see any policy about a previous published paper in a conference, however there is a policy as the following:

> The submission has not been previously published, nor is it before
>   another journal for consideration (or an explanation has been provided
>   in Comments to the Editor).

Could I send my paper to this journal?

Is it a normal thing to first publish a paper in  a conference and then trying to send it to a journal?

Comment: In any case you should mention the conference publication when you submit your manuscript, so that the editor can make sure this is acceptable.

Answer (score 6):

In my field this would be not only acceptable, but expected, as the review process for conferences is less stringent and the submitted abstracts are substantially less detailed than a full manuscript. A conference presentation is viewed almost as a necessary step to publication: present the first interpretation of the results, get feedback from colleagues, and incorporate changes into the full-length manuscript.

My only concern would be if the conference paper was closer to a full manuscript, both in length and in the rigorousness of the review process.

Answer (score 0):

A conference poster is a publication. At the very least, it is most likely in the Conference programme. It is unethical to publish the same material twice - and if the editor of the journal finds out, it is likely you'll be blacklisted. However, if you make changes to the poster - improvements, generalisations, etc. - then it *might* count as a new publication. Of course, you'll have referenced the poster in the new publication so the referees (and editor) will be able to tell if it's new material and suitable for publication.

Comment: On what basis are you making this claim? I'm curious if this is specific to your field, because it is flat-out incorrect in my experience. I understand that in computer science and mathematics (and perhaps other fields) the conference proceedings undergo rather rigorous peer review, but in the biomedical sciences, a conference poster is almost never considered a publication, because it lacks the rigorous peer review of a full-length journal article. Moreover, citing a conference paper instead of a peer-reviewed article is an option of last resort, and is viewed with skepticism.